# redirect using htaccess from subdomain to domain (individual files)

Tags: .htaccess

I have a subdomain (store.example.com). Not only do I want to redirect traffic from store.example.com but I want to redirect it to specific files on the domain (everything I could find was based on redirecting the entire subdomain)

So I want store.example.com/Science-Fiction -> www.bundoranpress.com/category/1/Science-Fiction

How would I write this using htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

You will either need a couple of RewriteConds or (in my opinion the better approach) a php script handling your requests. For the first approach:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(ThanksForAllTheFish) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.bundoranpress.com/$1/$2 [L,R]
```

This will redirect store.example.com/ThanksForAllTheFish to www.bundoranpress.com/store/ThanksForAllTheFish selling Douglas Adam's books.
Now, you could go for adding all possible terms in the second RewriteCond like so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(ThanksForAllTheFish|Universe|Hitchhiking) [NC]
```

This would capture one of the terms and redirect to the corresponding address (e.g. www.bundoranpress.com/store/Universe). You see that this will be difficult very quickly.
A better approach would be to redirect *all* urls from a specific folder and subdomain to a php script handling the rest, like so:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^books/(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.bundoranpress.com/index.php?sub=$1&cat=$2 [L,R]
```

This would redirect store.example.com/books/ThanksForAllTheFish to www.bundoranpress.com/index.php?sub=store&cat=ThanksForAllTheFish. You could access the variables via $_GET["sub"] and $_GET["cat"] respectively. This gives you a much greater flexibility at hand.